# SQL Server FOR XML Query with XSLT header

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xslt

I've built a SQL Server Query using FOR XML PATH as a stored procedure and I'd like to link the output to an XSL template that I've created. Is there a way to generate the output to include the XML header with the XSL header in it?

i.e.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

 <?xml-stylesheet href="REPORT1.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
```

Above my query output?

I'd like to call it from an ODBC request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out....
Add this to the beginning of the query:

```
 SELECT '<?xml version="1.0"?><?xml-stylesheet href="REPORT1.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>'+
```

And put () around the rest of the XML query.

Easy Peasy.